# Install qmake in debian 7.11

Tags: linux, debian, qmake

I'm using debian 7.11.

I is said qt5 is not supported by apt-get.

```
$apt-get install qt4-qmake
```

it works.

However,

```
$apt-get install qt5-qmake

E: Unable to locate package qt5-qmake
```

Is there any work-around way to install qt5 in debian 7?

These are my sources.list

```
$less /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://apt.readynas.com/packages/readynasos 6.5.1 updates apps main

deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

deb http://egnyte-cdn.egnyte.com/storagesync/netgear6/en-us 6.5 egnyte
deb ftp://ftp.nerim.net/debian-marillat/ stable main
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this gist:

- https://gist.github.com/iginosilva/fff315ff3072045e9819b6a268b4fdf2

  ```
  sudo apt-get install qt5-default
  ```

It worked for Ubuntu 16 xenial

```
qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Which I think that is the correct qmake.  you can check the build input on GitHub:

- https://github.com/qt/qtbase/tree/5.6/qmake

At present the latest Qt version seems to be something like 5.11 or better.  However one must acknowledge that released packages will (needs be) lag the *bleeding edge*.

Answer (score 0):

If I saw things correctly, Qt 5 is available in the Jessie repositories

You should either install a debian based on Jessie (so you only use packages from it) or add the repositories from Jessie in your sources.list (copy the lines from stable and change the target to testing), sync and install Qt 5

Change Wheezy example:

`deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main`

to Jessie:

`deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main`

Hope it helps